# How do I get the key alias file for Android? Do I need it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

I recently changed computers, and I had no trouble getting the keystore file. However, I cannot find the key alias file. Do I need that or is it bundled with the keystore?

Comment: I think, key store is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only the keystore, you can make new alias for every release , or just use one for all releases, also even for all apps, the key alias is a "pointer" for your certification key not a part of it.

For more about this you can see this link : [KeyStore and Key Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663991/keystore-and-key-alias)

This too: [Android: What is a keystore file, and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849558/android-what-is-a-keystore-file-and-what-is-it-used-for)

and this : [Understanding keystore, certificates and alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724631/understanding-keystore-certificates-and-alias)

Comment: I have done like this - made new key alias keeping Keystore the same as the old release. But after uploading to google play store it says that the SHA1 certificate of the new and old don't match.