# Building Indic Keyboard

Tags: java, android, build, package

I was trying to build the [Indic Keyboard](https://github.com/smc/Indic-Keyboard) project from github with android studio. Following the instruction I cloned the project and from the terminal of android studio typed commands

```
cd java
gradlew assembleDebug
```

At one stage in building it appears

> Enter keystore path:

followed by  keystore password, key alias, key password.

Where to find those value to enter? Also, am I in the correct path to build the project as I am pretty new in android development.

Comment: how can i setup this project on android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [GaRRaPeTa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27065677/4427731),

The "official" way to configure the build.gradle file as recommended by Google is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#configureSigning).

Basically, you add a signingConfig, in where you specify the location an password of the keystore. Then, in the release build type, refer to that signing configuration.

```
...
android {
...
defaultConfig { ... }
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
        keyPassword "password"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
}
...
```