# statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR in google login

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, android-googleapiclient, google-developer-tools

Below code I am using for Google login.I  added `google-services.json` file in the app folder.I am using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0`' in root gradle module.I have checked my package at developer console and its correct and I added SHA1 key which i got by running command `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android` on terminal(i am using ubuntu).I have enable Google+ API.I have created OAuth consent screen andOAuth client id.Still i get below error when i try to login with google-

> {statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

I check similar question but couldn't find appropriate solution.
Code

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestProfile().requestId()
            .requestEmail().requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    googleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } 
    }
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            // updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- To use account credentials -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 7):

It's likely that your issue is in that you picked the SHA1 from the `~/.android/debug.keystore`, but not using it to sign your build.

1. Go to the module options Signing tab and add a profile with the only field `Store File` set to `/Users/<your_user>/.android/debug.keystore`
2. On the Flavors tab pick it in the `Signing Config` drop-down.
3. On the Build Types tab pick it in the `Signing Config` drop-down for your build type (likely to be `Debug`).
4. Cleanup and rebuild.

Comment: This was my problem years later in Android Studio 2021, so this is still a problem! My project was generated from React Native so perhaps that caused it. I couldn't find the menu items you mention, but the setting was under `build.gradle:app: signingConfigs{debug{storeFile}}` which was set to `file('debug.keystore')` - once I fully pathed it and rebuild my app it resigned it with a different key (the emulator warned me the app had to be deleted which was a good sign). Then the code 10 was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working in two computer different, you have to generate the SHA1 again and add to console.firebase.google.com, download the google-service.json and add in your project

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061410/4696610) has worked.
Hope this will help you and others.

Apply the plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
```

> ***Make Sure this applicationId is same as your package name in Manifest file (Upper case and lower case matters)***

```
        applicationId "com.example" 
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 here.  For some reason (user error?), the app id in my manifest "com.company.appname" was reversed in my app's build.gradle file: "company.com.appname".   Correcting this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use .requestIdToken(BACKEND_CLIENT_ID) with your GoogleSignInOptions.

How to get the BACKEND_CLIENT_ID can be found here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 3):

solved by adding **SHA-1** of **debug key store** in firebase console for my app
which is located here
**C:\Users\my name.android**
when you make key store for **release** change it in firebase console

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Aleksey Gureiev for hinting... I solved my problem by making sure debug keys are actually used during builds..

For me in Android Studio the issue was the Signing Config was not set at all. I am still wondering how it happened.

Once I set Signing Config to my config with name "debug" then it all started working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my `React Native` project.

I had to generate `SHA-1 key` using `debug.keystore in android/app` folder.

Run the below command in the terminal after changing your directory to `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin`. (You may have a different JDK version).

`keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\{ProjectName}\android\app\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`