# DEVELOPER_ERROR (statusCode=10) in fetching LocationSettingsResult

Tags: java, android, location, google-play-services, android-location

We are getting error when getting location in some VIVO phones.

> DEVELOPER_ERROR (statusCode=10)

in the class LocationSettingsResult callback

below are the code.

```
  if (locationSettingsResult != null) {
            locationSettingsResult.setResultCallback(locationSettingsResult1 -> {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult1.getStatus();

                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        showRemarksDialogIfRequired();
                        break;

                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        try {
                            if (status.hasResolution()) {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(parentActivity, 333);
                            }
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        break;

                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "Can not set GPS settings for location!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Probably a key related issue . Double check your configurations.

Comment: I have double checked keys, it works perfectly on other devices excepts some VIVO phones. I can't find any issues on other phones. and for LocationRequest i don't think we require any keys.

Comment: Please see this links:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421518/statuscode-developer-error-in-google-login and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null