# React-native google signin gives Developer Error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying Google login using [React-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin) plugin but it gives me a Developer_Error.I have done exctly same as mention in its document.here is my code ans steps.

1.Installed react-native-google-signin plugin using npm i react-native-google-signin.
2.Then have linked it with react-native link react-native-google-signin
3.After that i did setup of build.gradle file as they mention it in the documents.

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' 
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' 
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
                mavenLocal()
                google() 
                maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
                jcenter()
                maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
                maven {
                    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                    name 'Google'
                }
        }
    }
```

4.Updated android/app/build.gradle,

```
    dependencies {

        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
        implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
        compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
        compile project(':react-native-fused-location')
        compile project(':react-native-fs')
        compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
        compile project(':react-native-geocoder')
        compile project(':react-native-device-info')
        compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
        compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation project(":react-native-google-signin")
        compile (project(':react-native-maps')){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" 
        }
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1' 

    }

    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

5.Then generate SHA1 key using android studion debug.keystore and generate google-services.json file in firebase.

6.Then setting up login.js page like this.

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        this._configureGoogleSignIn();

    }
    _configureGoogleSignIn() {
        GoogleSignin.configure({
            webClientId: '775060548127-5nfj43q15l75va9pfav2jettkha7hm2a.apps.googleusercontent.com',// my clientID
            offlineAccess: false
        });
    }
    async GoogleSignin() {
    try {
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
        const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
        // this.setState({ userInfo, error: null });
        Alert.alert("success:" + JSON.stringify(userInfo));

    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            // sign in was cancelled
            Alert.alert('cancelled');
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
            // operation in progress already
            Alert.alert('in progress');
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
            Alert.alert('play services not available or outdated');
        } else {
            Alert.alert('Something went wrong', error.toString());
            this.setState({
                error,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

These are my details so please someone help me on this i cannot find the appropriate solution online.and yes my SHA1 and clientID is correct i have cheked it already.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: no net yet ,have you got any solution then share it with me

Comment: No, I am getting the same error.. don't get it.. should be a basic integration..

Comment: Do you using firebase for backend?

Comment: For me it was trying to login via the simulator, but it was working on a physical device.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had this problem too and trawled through many answers saying check your client Id and key hash, both of which I was positive were right.

The thing that got it working for me was I opened OAuth identities in the project management console (not Firebase) at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials and added an Android Oauth client Id with the correct signature (I did not have one of these there prior for some reason). Redownload the GoogleServices json file.

I also needed to set the webClientId to the "client_type": 3 Oauth client ID. It then worked.

Comment: Can you explain; "I also needed to set the webClientId to the "client_type": 3 Oauth client ID. It then worked." ?

Comment: I am a little unsure this was a while ago, but in my google-services.json file I have an oauth_client where one of the objects contains a "client_type" equal to 3. I am assuming I meant use the "client_id" in that file where the "client_type" === 3

Comment: Hmm okay. Thanks for your reply. I've got it working in develop mode, but it still breaks with the developer error in React Native production build :(

Comment: @ronnyrr please verify that while creating the signed apk for production you are pointing to the correct keystore location. Default alias and password are: androiddebugkey /android

Comment: It's not working for me. I have tried every every thing. Please can somebody help? :'(

Answer (score 60):

Walkthrough for different modes:

#### Development Firebase

1. run `cd android && ./gradlew signingReport`.
2. Copy the SHA-1 hash and paste it into the firebase console under Android in Project Settings.
3. Download the `google-services.json` file from the Firebase settings and paste the file into `android/app`
4. Use the client `client_type: 3` clientId inside the config.

#### Development non-Firebase

1. run `cd android && ./gradlew signingReport`.
2. Copy the SHA-1 hash
3. Go to [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and click `Create Credentials` -> `OAuthClientID`. Choose type `Android` and paste the hash and fill in the form
4. Create another Client by clicking `Create Credentials`, but choose type `Web application` this time.
5. Use the webclient in your code

#### Production/Release version

1. Go to the Google Play console and copy SHA-1 key from `Release -> Setup -> App Integrity`
2. Go to [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and click `Create Credentials` -> `OAuthClientID`. Choose type `Android` and paste the hash and fill in the form
3. Create another Client by clicking `Create Credentials`, but choose type `Web application` this time.
4. Use the webclient in your code

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Make sure to follow step 1 under "Production/Release version", I spent an entire weekend trying to figure out why sign-in was failing only when downloading the app from the PlayStore.

Comment: This worked!! I have struggled with this issue for quite some time and apparently, I have been using the wrong SHA1. The `./gradlew signingReport` command shows exactly which to use for which build. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain in detail.

Comment: Finally worked for me when I used the SHA-1 key from the Upload key certificate instead of the App signing key certificate. Both are found in the Google play console App Integrity section.

Comment: What a clear explanation, thank you!

Comment: When you add SHA-1 from Firebase Console, the Google Cloud Platform Console A is also added. The method above did not work in me after adding Firebase Console, I had to update Google-Services.json file

Comment: Resolved the error for me.

Comment: For Expo/EAS, I created two Android credentials (the two SHA1 values from `Release -> Setup -> App Signing` in the Play Console). The first uses the SHA1 from `Upload key certificate` which comes up the same as the SHA1 listed in EAS credentials. The second using the SHA1 from `App signing key certificate` (I believe this is the production signing key when you submit to the Play Store if you use Google managed signing). Once both of these were set up, I could log in from both my development client and the version from the Play Store.

Comment: when i use this on expo project it print out many SHA1 key, use which start with
Variant: debug
Config: debug

Comment: Thank you! It's appalling how poorly documented this is

Comment: Does this solution work for internal testing Im choosing Development firebase mode

Answer (score 33):

I was trying keytool `-exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v` which of course was giving me a SHA1 key but it was not working, after searching for a while I also look closer into my `project/android/app` folder and found that there is a `debug.keystore` key too (whose default password is `android`, in case some need to know ) so I tried `cd android` and `keytool -exportcert -keystore app/debug.keystore -list -v` command and the key I got, worked really well. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I had to add the specific key for the app not the one located in ~/.android

Comment: Love you... Thanks... :)

Comment: I got: "Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified."

Comment: I put my 3 days but I was not successful but your answer help me, thanks bro

Comment: this comment works for me. at first i had my own keystore file and generated SHA1 fingerprint from it didn't work, then i changed to generate the fingerprint from default debug.keystore now it's work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved lot of my time!

Answer (score 10):

For React native projects:

There are many items in the checklist to get rid of DEVELOPER_ERROR. There seems to be lot of confusion around where the SHA-1 key needs to be set.

Once you have created android client_id in Google developer console you have an option to set SHA-1 key and package name.

You can get the package name from AndroidManifest.xml `(projPath/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)` and set it in the text box in google developer console(very important to check for typos).

Then fetch your SHA-1 key from debug.keystore using following command for which password is "android"

First figure out location of keystore:

Your app may be either picking from

```
     `pathToReactNativeProj/projName/android/app/debug.keystore`
```

or:     `~/.android/debug.keystore`

Then fetch your SHA-1 key from debug.keystore using following command for which password is `android`

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore pathToKeyStore -list -v`

copy paste the SHA-1 key generated . This should solve the issue.

Code looks like following:

```
try {
      GoogleSignin.configure(
      {
        //webClientId is required if you need offline access
        offlineAccess: true,
        webClientId:'2423432-43234234232432423234.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        androidClientId: '3242343242322432-2342323432232324343323.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scopes: ['profile', 'email']
      });
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      console.log("reached google sign in");
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log(userInfo);
      this.setState({ userInfo });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log("error occured SIGN_IN_CANCELLED");
        // user cancelled the login flow
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log("error occured IN_PROGRESS");
        // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log("error occured PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE");
      } else {
        console.log(error)
        console.log("error occured unknow error");
      }
    }
```

Confusion around firebase SHA-1 key:

Setting this key is not required for fetching user info from google. Unless you are using firebase to store your users data you fetched from google you need not worry about it.

Comment: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore pathToKeyStore -list -v`, this command gives me error `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.` so i used without -exportcert `keytool -keystore app/debug.keystore -list -v`

Answer (score 10):

For those who are still looking for solutions:

1. Please match your key fingerprint in firebase console.
2. Do not initialize the configuration with keys, I repeat, do not provide any configuration object in the .configure() function
   Do this `GoogleSignIn.configure()`.
3. Point 2 will resolve the issue. :)

Comment: you mean dont' provide webClientId keys inside GoogleSignIn.configure()?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do not add webClientId?

Comment: it works, but i still can't understand why not to supply client id

Answer (score 8):

In my case, my SHA-1 key that I added to firebase project is invalid because I got it from `/Users/apple/.android/debug.keystore`.

The correct SHA-1 should be in the android folder inside the Project example: `/Users/apple/Documents/Project/testGoogleFirebaseLogin/android/app/debug.keystore` (testGoogleFirebaseLogin is my project folder name)

So, the most convenient way is `cd android && ./gradlew signingReport`. It will generate many many lines of data, scroll down and look for SHA-1 from the one that has `Store: (your project path)`

NOTE: Not the one that has `Store: /Users/apple/.android/debug.keystore`.

(Apologize to my English skill, I will be appreciated if some one correct my gramma and make this answer is easier to read)

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my issue. I needed to upload a new key from a new device.

Comment: This puzzled me for days! All the guides just say to get the SHA1 you get from the default command. It needs to be the one specific to your project, Thanks!!!

Comment: OMG!! I was stuck for HOURSS!! You saved my asss!!! Thank you <33

Answer (score 8):

works for me:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore app/debug.keystore
```

get SHA1 and add in console of firebase

Answer (score 5):

It's just because of your `androidClientId` is a mismatch as your google console project

1. create your new auth client id from your project API console : https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials [image]
2. update configuration to: `myfile.js` like:

> GoogleSignin.configure({
>    androidClientId:'YOUR CLIENT ID'
>   )}
>   [image]

Comment: There is no androidClientId parameter within new firebase version

Answer (score 3):

**Folks who use Firebase for Google Sign in**

I am posting this answer because I did try a lot of methods and only this was working fine for me. The issue is happening because, in the RN version 0.61, a new `debug.keystore` was introduced. Due to this, the existing/new projects are affected.

To solve this,

1. Generate a new android debug key under `android/app` folder. Go to the root folder of your react native app and run the below command.

> keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/app/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Once the above command ran, it will show the `SHA1` in the terminal. Copy it.

2. Go to your project `firebase.console` and under your `General` tab in the `project settings`, paste the copied `SHA1` and save it.

Done. Now run the app and it should work fine.

For more info, https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues/823

Answer (score 3):

the issus for me was, using the webClientID, without the androidClientID.

- webClientID: in google-services.json => "client_type": 3
- androidClientID: in google-services.json => "client_type": 1
  Then in your file js:

  ```
   GoogleSignin.configure({
        androidClientId:
  "something.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        webClientId:
   "something.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   });
  ```

Answer (score 2):

In react native theres 2 types of keystores:

- debug.keystore: just for debuging.
- yourownkeystore.keystore: this one is for production. and you need to create it. check this link to know how: https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

while in production. while creating yourownkeystore.keystore. you ll get a specific SHA-1 that will be used for production. take that one for yourownkeystore.keystore and replace it in the firebase console of your project. then redownload the google-services.json file and replace it in your android/app. then get the clientID and the androidID from that json file and place them in the configuration of your google Signing method in js.

Comment: You saved my life. for those using Keystore generate through Android studio **".jks"** you can follow these links [SHA-1 fingerprint of Keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931) to generate your SHA1. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think sometime it may possible for an old fingerprint (from a different dev in a former time) could be conflicting. So SHA1 should be proper. Delete the old SHA-1 and re-download google-services.json

Answer (score 1):

Add SHA1 key value to the google-services.json file. For that open the google-services.json
file in any text editor and add

`"certificate_hash": "5e8f16062ea3cd2c4a0d547876baa6f38cabf625"`

with your hash value without a colon (:) in `android_client_info`

Demo google-services.json file

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "108005055433",
    "firebase_url": "https://se-ai-camera.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "demo-app",
    "storage_bucket": "demo-app.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:108005055433:android:323bf88853cd2899872618",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.myapp",
          "certificate_hash": "5e8f16062ea3cd2c4a0d547876baa6f38cabf625"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "108005055433-q748qmcrn9a3j4qmg9srrkbotvr4emh1.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyAuGCMQoW0tM7QMhpAgMIi0sK3vj0Nj8lk"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "108005055433-q748qmcrn9a3j4qmg9srrkbotvr4emh1.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

or add SHA1 key in the ([firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)) app settings and download the updated google-services.json file.

**Then change the GoogleSignIn.configure() method parameter as empty.**  This is the most important step.

Answer (score 1):

Check you're added the debug and release fingerprints in firebase project settings

Other wise create the debug & release key fingerprints by using the `app/build.gradle -> signingConfigs -> debug`

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore android/app/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android


$ keytool -list -v -keystore android/app/release.keystore -alias androidrelease-aliaskey -storepass android -keypass android
```

then copy the sha1/sha256 fingerprints and add it to the `project settings -> firebase`

Answer (score 1):

try these, ***don't use webClientId and offlineAccess: true***

```
 GoogleSignin.configure({
     ClientId:
        '48774575517-o9j0crni6shsal3jnoerm1o19pdqkg05.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      
    });
```

it's helped me and I don't use firebase,googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1",classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1',***nothing***

just I install

1. npm i @react-native-google-signin/google-signin
2. cd android and gradlew clean

Now run the app and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me above all answers. May be it was more simple and clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you must install `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin`

and follow this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck in this situation when i was publishing my first app.
React Native documentation tells about generating a keystore.
But as i was using firebase for google auth, it needs sha of that keystore to be mentioned in project settings.

To get the SHA1 from the generated keystore, run these commands :

```
cd android
cd app

keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore-name}.keystore -alias {alias-name}
```

Now it will ask for password. enter the password you created while generating the keystore.
It will print all details & here you can find the SHA1.
Copy the SHA1 fingerprint & add in your firebase console > project settings > android app

Answer (score 0):

What happened with me can be extremely rare but still posting here incase someone face it too because I spent a whole day in this.
So for me my SHA1 keys were also fine on both google cloud locally and firebase everything was perfect still it was only working on debug build and on release builds I was getting a DEVELOPER ERROR.

after spending lot of time we got to know that whatever we were changing was not getting included in the release build instead we were getting a cached version every time. and finally we get it solved by clearing the cache by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61060628/11490859) .

Answer (score 0):

I had this error appearing after I upload the app to the play store and after a week of hitting my head here and there. I found that Google has launched a new signings service where they sign your app on the play store after you upload, with their key after which they give you SHA1 for the same on the play store developer console.

> under  > Release Management > App Signing

take SHA-1 from there and add it to your Firebase project app. And yay! it worked for me and hopefully will work for you if you are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v which of course was giving me a SHA1 key but it was not working, after searching for a while I also look closer into my project/android/app folder and found that there is a debug.keystore key too (whose default password is android, in case some need to know ) so I tried cd android and keytool -exportcert -keystore app/debug.keystore -list -v command and the key I got, worked really well. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was calling for `idToken` by having `webClientId` and `offlineAccess` as true. Turns out my `webClientId` value was not correct. I set its value from `google-services.json` obtained from firebase console with `client_id` value from `client_type` 3.

Comment: Did you leave offlineAccess as true?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Create release keystore by following methods given in react native official website https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

**Step 2:**

**generate debug SHA1** key by using given command line:

```
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

**Step 3:**

Copy and paste SHA1 project section
[image]

**Step 4:**

**generate release (Important) SHA1 key** by using given command line (give full path of your debug keystore file):

```
keytool -keystore "E:\<You Project folder name>\android\app\my-upload-key.keystore" -list -v
```

add to firebase project section by clicking `add fingerprint`
[image]

**Step 5:**

get your `Web client ID` from `Authentication > Google > Web SDK configuration > Web client ID`

[image]

and use in your project in `GoogleSignIn Configure()` like this:

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  scopes: [], // what API you want to access on behalf of the user, default is email and profile
  webClientId: '<Paste here Your copied web client ID>', // client ID of type WEB for your server (needed to verify user ID and offline access)
  offlineAccess: true, // if you want to access Google API on behalf of the user FROM YOUR SERVER
  // hostedDomain: '', // specifies a hosted domain restriction
  // forceCodeForRefreshToken: true, // [Android] related to `serverAuthCode`, read the docs link below *.
  // accountName: '', // [Android] specifies an account name on the device that should be used
  // iosClientId: '<FROM DEVELOPER CONSOLE>', // [iOS] if you want to specify the client ID of type iOS (otherwise, it is taken from GoogleService-Info.plist)
  // googleServicePlistPath: '', // [iOS] if you renamed your GoogleService-Info file, new name here, e.g. GoogleService-Info-Staging
  // openIdRealm: '', // [iOS] The OpenID2 realm of the home web server. This allows Google to include the user's OpenID Identifier in the OpenID Connect ID token.
  // profileImageSize: 120, // [iOS] The desired height (and width) of the profile image. Defaults to 120px
});
```

**That's all** I hope It will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check your WEBCLIENTID ID

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34195363)

Answer (score 0):

{
"client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"client_type": 3
}
setting webclientid with client_type 3 resolves issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 for Firebase and Google Credentials you should take from `keytool -keystore app/debug.keystore -list -v` (password: `android`).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

This generates two variant keys. You can copy the SHA1 that belongs to the debugAndroidTest variant key option.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, this error is most likely due to SHA1 keys not matching.

If you are building with Expo eas and also submitting the app through eas, then note that for Android apps, if you have published through Play App signing (which eas does), Google will sign each of your release. See: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

"If you've published your app using Play App Signing, a requirement when using Android App Bundle, you can get your SHA-1 from the Google Play Console on the Release > Setup > App Integrity page."

This SHA1 is missing in your Firebase SHA certificate fingerprints for your android app, hence why you are getting DEVELOPER_ERROR on production builds only.

To fix:

1. Go to [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console) -> Release -> Setup -> App Signing and copy the App signing key certificate SHA-1 certificate fingerprint
2. Add the SHA-1 to your Firebase SHA certificate fingerprints for your android app in your Firebase project settings
3. Download the new google-services.json file, and update your source code. Build and submit.

A couple callouts, to save your time:

- react-native-google-signin/google-signin ConfigureParams no longer has androidClientId option. You need to pass in the webClientId and offlineAccess. Only calling GoogleSignin.configure() will throw an argument error.
- running eas credentials will give you the SHA-1 certificate EAS used to sign your app. You don't need to have access to your android folder to do this, if you are in a managed workflow. You can also include this in your Firebase SHA certificate fingerprints. This is what you need for GoogleSignin to work on your development client build.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting DEVELOPER-ERROR when creating a release APK in React Native in (2023)

if the Google singing has been set correctly and Google signIn works correctly in debug mode but gives DEVELOPER-ERROR in the release apk then generate release keystore in  **C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.20.8-hotspot\bin** or the directory in which you have installed jdk then run the following commands:

1. **keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-keystore.jks -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**
2. add password & confirm password
3. Now navigate to project directory
4. type **cd android**
5. **keytool -list -v -keystore "E:\Hakathon App\ProjectName\android\app\my-key.keystore"**
6. Enter the keystore password again
7. The SHA-1 key will be shown in the Certificate fingerprints
8. Now add this SHA-1 key to the Firebase project
9. Now download the new google-service.json file
10. Add it to your project
11. Now run the command **npm run android -- --mode="release"**

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in production.

- We got SH1 by command to production keystore but this didn't help us
  keytool -keystore /Users/user1/disk/apptracker.keystore -list -v
- As a cliendId we used webClientID (not Android)
- Later we changed "Publishing status" to "In production" and the error disappears

Answer (score 0):

1. go to google cloud console
2. go to api and services > go to credentials
3. click create credentials > go to OAuth client ID
4. click on web application on application type and click create and it will create client id and client secret
5. click on a android in application type and enter the package name and sha-1 in it and it will also create client id for android.
6. note: to generate sha-1 you can do the following
7. cd android
8. ./gradlew signingReport
9. now enter the client id of web in the react-native google sign in

```js
useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      scopes: ['profile'],
      webClientId:
        'your web client id',
      forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    });
    isSignedIn();
  }, []);
```