# React-native google signin is not working properly in release mode

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

I am using [react-native-google-signin / google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) . `Google-signin` is working as expected in `Debug mode`. But In `Release mode` some times getting `Developer Error`. I have done configuration according to this [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417232/react-native-google-signin-gives-developer-error).

IF I get `Developer Error` in each and every login then I can check for any configuration mistakes. But in my case, in debug mode every time it's working as expected. In `Release mode` some times it's working , some times it's giving `Developer Error`.

1. Am I missing any additional configuration steps?

or

2. Is App unable to get `webclientid` sometimes?(I am just raising this concern based on what's happening in my app).

Comment: are you using firebase or not?

Comment: @Xhirazi Yes, I am using firebase.

Comment: Did you add SHA certificate fingerprints?

Comment: Also check if you enable Google login  under Authentication>Sign in Method

Comment: @Xhirazi I have enabled google login and SHA1 certificate fingerprints added and downloaded .json file. Still am I missing something?

Comment: on which OS you are unable to login in iOS or Android or both?

Comment: @Xhirazi in Android only

Comment: One more question, are you getting this error on (dev) release mode or when you download the released app from Google playstore?

Comment: @Xhirazi when I downloaded form playstore.

Comment: You need to add the same fingerprint (SHA1) to playstore aswell. it will solve you issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are missing SHA-1 certificate in Firebase from Playstore which is causing you this issue.

You can get SHA-1 to Playstore by going to `Release Managment > App signing` and add this this firebase console aswell.

P.S:
Don't remove the previous one

Comment: I found a strange thing that, once I login into debug app and delete, then download from playstore and try to login it works fine. But for the first time if I try to login into play store app then google sign in won't work. what could be the reason?

Comment: I found that SHA-1 certificate in firebase and playstore are different. But there is no option to add update SHA-1 certificate.

Comment: can you regenerate SHA-1 and verify which one is correct?

Comment: If I regenerate SH1-1 won't be there any problem to update the app next time?

Comment: No. But if you change keystore for apk update it wont hapen

Comment: And SHA can only be generated by keystore/keytool. Please confirm which SHA-1 is correct either firebase or playstore

Comment: then you need to change SHA-1 in Playstore.

Comment: But As I said earlier, There is no option update or add new SHA-1. DO you aware of updating or adding new SHA-1 in playstore?

Comment: My Bad. Actually you need to copy SHA-1 from Playstore and add this it to firbase aswell (don't remove previous one)

Comment: I have update the answer. please let me know if it can help.

Comment: "I found a strange thing that, once I login into debug app and delete, then download from playstore and try to login it works fine. But for the first time if I try to login into play store app then google sign in won't work. what could be the reason?"

I am experiencing exactly this. I have copied the Play App Signing key SHA1 to google cloud and firebase but still no luck.