# Google Sign In not working in debug mode

Tags: android, google-signin

I have followed all the steps outlined in the Google Docs the explain the integration in Android apps. I have generated both my debug and release SHA-1 keys and set them in the console; then downloaded the generated `google-services.json` file which I subsequently added to my project's `app` folder.

When I try to sign in with Google in debug mode, I get this error `handleSignInResult:Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}`. 
I get though to the dialog that allows me to select with which profile I'd like to sign in with, but on the `onActivityResult` method, I have the following code that logs the `GoogleSignInResult` status:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.getStatus().toString());

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();

            if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
                String idToken = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I generate a signed apk and try to log in, it works fine.

I'm boggled as to what would cause this to happen. FYI, I could sign in without any problems until a few hours ago.

I haven't made any change regarding Google sign in or in the dependent libraries.

Comment: please, update your question with the line you place the breakpoint

Comment: @GuilhermeFGL check updated question

Comment: Where is the breakpoint in your code? In with line?

Comment: To solve the problem `handleSignInResult:Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}` take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44506538/8405762

Comment: @GuilhermeFGL I had already referred to that question before. All the keys are already in the Firebase console configuration i.e the debug and release SHA-1 keys. The issue is unique to running the app in debug mode. It works fine when i generate a signed apk.

Comment: Look at my answer here and see if it helps for the debug mode https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883466/9747826