# How do I solve DEVELOPER_ERROR in GoogleSignIn Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-oauth, sha1, google-signin

I have uploaded my application on the `Google Play`. `Facebook` login works fine but when I try to login using `Google` Login, it's throwing

> statusCode="DEVELOPER_ERROR"

I have added the 2 `SHA1` fingerprints to `FIREBASE (debug and release)` but I still see this error.

I generate the signed `APK` in `Android Studio` and then I install this `APK` on several phones and it works and I can log in!

The problem happens when I download the app from the `Google Play`. Any help please?

Comment: Take a look at this answer and make sure you added the SHA1 fingerprint correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44506538/6243324.

Comment: I did it.. but it is showing the DEBUG SHA1... It's currently added on Firebase (it's the same one) @Sub6Resources

Comment: The problem only happens when you download you app from the play store, not while you are developing it?

Comment: @Sub6Resources Exactly. When I download the app f from Google Play and install it. If I generate a signed APK from Android Studio and then I install it on my phone (sending the APK by google drive) I can log in perfectly. Also when I am debugging the log in is successful.

Comment: Are you using the same package name?

Comment: @Sub6Resources The same one... I don't know what else I should do

Comment: How long has your project existed on Firebase? I know that I had to set up a new Firebase project for one of my older apps due to an issue with the SHA1 codes.