# Android Google+ sign-in issue

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus

I have a android application that with `Google+` sign-in function. I have enabled Google+ API and create `oauth 2.0` user client id for my application. Also, I download the JSON file from `https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?`platform=android. I generate the signed apk(release) and the google+ sign-in function works.
My problem is that if I upload the signed apk to google play as a beta version. The Google+ sign-in function will be failed!!! The error sign-in result: Status

> {statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}.

I have no idea about this condition, please have advised to me. Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null)

Comment: You can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38496053/8143436

Answer (score 0):

Generate and add your SHA1 key to the Google Project Console. This will solve your issue.

keytool -list -v -keystore KEYSTORE_PATH -alias ALIAS_NAME

Use your Release keystore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter SHA 1 certificate fingerprints from Google Play Console to your Google Project Console. Generated release SHA1 fingerprints works for signed apk but doesn't work for live apps anymore.

Comment: Can you provide url link to Google Project Console? Do you mean firebase project console?

Comment: No, Google provides SHA1 fingerprint on Google Play console ,from where you have published your app.
Put that SHA1 certificate on your google/firebase developer console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your SHA1 key to firebase console configuration.
You can do it in this way:

Firebase console ( https://console.firebase.google.com )  -> your project -> configuration -> scroll to

[image]

You can find your SHA1 key running "Signin report" from Android Studio:

[image]

Then, look the "run tab" and click the button:

[image]

I think it's the easier way. Hope this help.