# Firebase is not accepting SHA1 for release keystore

Tags: android, firebase, google-authentication

I have implemented google login in my app, it works fine in debug apk, as debug SHA1 is stored in firebase.

**I cant login using google in my signed apk, error says "statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR"**

i did a little digging on it and found that release sha needs to be added to firebase console

**I tried adding release sha1 to firebase console, but it is not allowing me to add it, error says:"Your operation was forbidden"**

Without release sha,google login won't work.

What is the way around it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null

Comment: i tried as this link suggested , made sha but firebase console is still not accepting it

Comment: If you see unexpected errors in the Firebase console, you should contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/