# Google sign-in integration login error DEVELOPER ERROR in Android

Tags: android, error-handling, google-signin, sha1

I have integrated Google login integration in my Application which is in live in Play store. Everything is working fine including google sign-in,if I generate the Apk using my Laptop. So I tried to generate the apk by using another laptop, then the issue comes, i.e, Google sign in not working. I debugged, and got the reason is  `{status code: developer error, resolution : null}`.

I find out the solution that this is due to **sha-1 key mismatch**
 If generate the sha1 key using keystore file, where should I put that in google console. no solutions are given the answer for this

Can some one please give me relevant solution  for this problem. any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. After changing physical machine you've to provide **SHA-1** of new machine to **Google Developer Console**, also note that debug and release variants have different SHA-1.

Comment: Can you please elaborate u r answer please. So that I can implement in that way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER\_ERROR, resolution=null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null)

Comment: check this answer to retrieve **SHA-1** in simple way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/10271334.

Comment: yes @JeelVankhede, now I working like that. I have generated sha 1 key from keystore file and this key different from the key present in playstore

Answer (score 0):

You are creating SHA 1 from debugging key so it will depend on the machine,You should creating SHA1 fingerprint from release mode

Check below command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

on this case, it will work from any machine

Comment: I got the Sha1 key from keystore file in this way.  where to use this?.  The key got here is different from that I have in playstore.

Comment: You should add it on your  Google API Console project

Comment: I have registered a app for google sign-in in Google console. should I restrict that api key?

Comment: where do add sha 1 key there?

Comment: I  can see here in google console that they have given commands to generate sha1 jey and I have put restriction to Android Apps..  Is this enough?

Comment: yes, every time you have to generate signed apk instead of using debug apk

Comment: If I add the release Sha 1 key there, will it impact the already installed users from playstore?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below changes, was facing the same

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[] {"com.google",null},false, null, null, null, null);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

to

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[] {"com.google"},false, null, null, null, null);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Removed  null argument after "com.google"