# Google Sign-In with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-play-developer-api, google-play-services

I am desperately trying to implement Google Sign-In ( for Leaderboards and Achievements), but I get a INTERNAL_ERROR, every time, I double-checked everything, both production and debug SHA-1 are present. However, I have accidentally linked my project to Firebase ( if there is a way to completely unlink it, please tell me, I've tried everything, in my Play Console there still is the Firebase Icon next to my app) and when I inspected the google-services.json file I got from Firebase, the entry

```
 "google_signin_service": {
      "status": 2
    },
```

(which I found in a sample .json file) was missing, NOW, what do I do ? Do I try and copy it in my json file ? Do I have to start an app all over again to implement the Sign-In, because apparently un-linking Projects does not work, thank you !

Comment: How do you manage the authentication with Firebase?

Comment: I've actually managed to make it work, I think the .json configuration file was not working, thank you for your time anyway

Comment: You can answer you own question for users having the same problem btw. ;)

Comment: Oh thanks, I did not know that :))

Answer (score 2):

I tried again, following these steps:

1. Got SHA1, both debug and release [SHA1 Key for DEBUG & RELEASE ANDROID STUDIO MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933380/sha1-key-for-debug-release-android-studio-mac)
2. Got JSON configuration, either from Google or Firebase,copied it in
   app folder
3. Followed Google API instructions
   https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup