# Google sign in doesn't work after publishing the app on playstore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am building an application with google sign in using firebase. But after I publish the app on playstore, the google sign in fails to work. I read few answers and I did use both the SHA keys for debug and release and then downloaded the google-services.json. Still the problem seems to persist. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Please check my-release-key.keystore. in project/app. ## if debug mode work ?

Comment: @Manjeet I can't find that in my app. Can you please tell me about it.

Comment: Please add more information, so the sof user can help you finding your problem. What is the error message? Build a signed debug build and tell us the logs.

Comment: Create new OAuth Client using release apk SHA1 key.
and below is link to follow 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites
Generate SHA key like below 

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias selvin -keystore c:\users\selvin\desktop\selvin.kp | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64

Comment: @DeewankshiSharma I am using Linux.

Comment: follow link and create release key SHA1
http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/obtaining-sha1-fingerprint-android-keystore/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert in android, but recently i had developed react-native android application and in app have login with google. i'm also facing same problem.

> **In my case:**

create release Android Signing Certificate SHA-1 by command or other way.
helping tutorial [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/obtaining-sha1-fingerprint-android-keystore/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933381/5115112)

[image]