# Google Sign in not working after app is published

Tags: android, google-signin, google-play-console

I have google login in my app which was working completely fine before publishing my app.But after publishing i am unable to sign in due to change in SHA key. So to change this i'm following steps in **Released Management->App Sigining** on my play console. 
I have downloaded **PEPK tool** but for step 2 I have command

```
$ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path
```

I dont know what is *foo.keystore*, *foo* and *encrypted_private_key_path*

can any one please help me on this?.

Comment: so I think you didn't read the docs correctly

Comment: Did you forget to add signature of the production keystore to the google authentication console?

Comment: @SamuelRobert yes i didnt add any thing to console after production. but i have no idea how to add signature there.

Answer (score 0):

While working with any of the APIs related to Google Developer Console in Android, you need to configure two different SHA1 keys, i.e. one for debug and one for release. It happens most of the times that, we forget to to generate the SHA1 key for release version. I believe following link will help you to generate SHA1 keys for both the versions.

[SHA1 Key for DEBUG & RELEASE ANDROID STUDIO MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933380/sha1-key-for-debug-release-android-studio-mac)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am getting keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format even when my jks file is on that location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Play Signing to allow Google Play to sign the release version of your app for you, then you will need to register the SHA1 key from the release version of your app with the authentication console. You can get this key following the instructions here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB

"If your app uses any API, you will usually need to register the certificate of the key Google signs your app with for authentication purposes. This is usually done through the fingerprint of the certificate.

To find the certificate of the key Google uses to re-sign your APK for delivery:

- Sign in to your Play Console.
- Select an app.
- On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
  From this page, you can copy the most common fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate. If the API provider requires a different type of fingerprint, you can also download the original certificate in DER format and run it through the transformation tools that the API provider requires."