# Unable to authenticate Gmail API in release version

Tags: android, release, gmail-api

I am working on an android app for our company. 
The app takes a photo and send it via e-mail to our server.

I want to use Gmail API to send the photo and the data. In debug mode vereything works fine and I can authenticate the Api and the Gmail account.

When I make a signed apk for the app and runs it on the same phone as i tested the debuf version on I cannot authenticate the Api and the Gmail account.

I create the signed apk but choosing Build->Create signed APK in android studio.

I have searched for a solution but not been able to make any sense of the answers I found.

I want to distribute the app via our corporate server rathern than via Google play.

Can you use the Gmail API in an release version of ann app without dirstributing it via Google Play?

Kind regards
Erik Johansson

Answer (score 0):

may be you have not put SHA1 key of your sign Apk in google cloud console. follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933380/sha1-key-for-debug-release-android-studio-mac/34933381?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) link for creating a SHA1 key for sign apk. And put package name and SHA1 key in [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

Comment: I am doin exatly what is said in the answers above but got error message "UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE"

Comment: show screen shot of your google api console with selected project

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your API key to use the release keystore along with the debug keystore file.

You need to get your SHA1 from your keystore file.

You can see how to do this here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

In a terminal, run the folowing Keytool utility command to get the SHA1 fingerprint you will use to enable the API.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/yourkeystore.keystore -list -v
```

When asked for a keystore password, enter your password.

You'll see a result like so:

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
Enter keystore password: Type "android" if using debug.keystore
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Dec 4, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 503bd581
Valid from: Mon Aug 27 13:16:01 PDT 2012 until: Wed Aug 20 13:16:01 PDT 2042
Certificate fingerprints:
   MD5:  1B:2B:2D:37:E1:CE:06:8B:A0:F0:73:05:3C:A3:63:DD
   SHA1: D8:AA:43:97:59:EE:C5:95:26:6A:07:EE:1C:37:8E:F4:F0:C8:05:C8
   SHA256: F3:6F:98:51:9A:DF:C3:15:4E:48:4B:0F:91:E3:3C:6A:A0:97:DC:0A:3F:B2:D2:E1:FE:23:57:F5:EB:AC:13:30
   Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
   Version: 3
```

Copy the SHA1 key which in this case is D8:AA:43:97:59:EE:C5:95:26:6A:07:EE:1C:37:8E:F4:F0:C8:05:C8 .

Add this to your API key and you'll be good to go. You can find this in the Google Developer API console linked here: 
https://console.cloud.google.com/

Do note that API key changes can take ten minutes to be live, so if it doesn't work straight away, try again in a 10 minutes.