# Error while implementing Google login in Android App 12500

Tags: android, google-signin

I am getting this strange error 12500 (sometimes 12502) code while google login. I saw some posts related to 12501 code and none seemed helpful. Also tried adding requestIdToken(web_client_id), no use. Please help!

I logged the response status, here it is:

```
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12500, resolution=null}
```

TIA

Comment: have you update sha on console ?

Comment: Its because you have not updated the google playstore version

Comment: is your app live or not ?

Comment: your apk is debug or release ?

Comment: My app is in live and i have updated it one hour before with this update

Comment: ya updated sha1 of both debug and release keys, app is live @SandeepMalik

Comment: playstore version or google services dependancy version? @g.brahmaDatta

Comment: did you using firebase?? in this project??

Comment: ya firebase @Aabauser

Comment: ok then you have to get a SHA1key from you google play store console and then update that also on your firebase console

Comment: @PSandeshBaliga is both firebase and playconsole account are same or not?

Comment: I have opted out of google play app signing. @SandeepMalik. So I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: No. Not same @Aabauser

Comment: I dont think it is problem with SHA1 key and the other error (12502) might be the exception when you clicked cancel for signing in

Comment: @PSandeshBaliga that's the issue you have to make it the same and add sha1 to the firebase project also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, somehow in Google API Console, It was asking for OAuth consent, and it was showing a popup to complete applying the same. 
I clicked on that dialog and did few procedures.
You'll have to enter

- Email Address
- App icon
- Domain url
- Terms URL for your website
- Privacy policy for your website

Then file the consent, After success and after a few minutes, Google login should work well.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this link and you will get a SHA from play store console and update it on your firebase console :-https://www.appdome.com/no-code-mobile-integration-knowledge-base/extracting-a-sha-1-fingerprint-from-the-google-play-app-signing-certificate/

and then you don't need to update a new apk on your console.

there will be 3 SHA1 on your firebase console :-

1) Debug SHA1.
2) Release SHA1.
3) Play Store Console SHA1.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same issue recently later I got know that the google play service version is not updated. By this question in stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/47645136/7352857

So I had to do this in the onActivityResult,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGNIN_ID){
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> googleSignInAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {

            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInAccountTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            fireBaseAuthenticationWithGoogle(googleSignInAccount);

        }catch (ApiException e){

            //if user doesn't have updated google play services version

            if (e.getStatusCode() == 12500){

                try{
                    // show your own AlertDialog for example:
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    // set the message
                    builder.setMessage("This app uses google play services for 
  signing in")
                            .setTitle("Do you want to update?");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialog, id) -> {

                        //final String appPackageName = "com.google.android.gms";
                        final String appPackageName = 
                    "com.google.android.gms&hl=en_IN";
                        try {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
               Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                        }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + 
             appPackageName)));
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }catch (Exception err){
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }else {
        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Try this and let me know if you have query.I solved this error by this method.

Comment: Fair enough, but once taken to playstore page of gms, it only shows deactivate option, not of update. Seems like no updated are available. Any workarounds?

Comment: If it already updated then you will not get the exception you can log in with one of your accounts I got it solved today. I had the same issue.

Comment: Still Im not able to login :(

Comment: Are you getting the error code as 12500 in exception for sure or any other?

Comment: code 12500 for sure, thats the exact log im getting (in the question)

Comment: Yes Its uploaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192368/discussion-between-g-brahma-datta-and-p-sandesh-baliga).

Comment: Hi, Ya I solved it by completing the OAuth consent in Google API console, turns out that was the issue leading to 12500

Comment: wow, that's great @PSandeshBaliga. And I got solved this error also when the google play services are not updated. Maybe in future you may have this problem. So just saying.

Answer (score 0):

RELEASE:

1. In android studio. Build -> Generate Signed APK... and click Next
2. Copy your key store path and key alias.
3. Open terminal and enter:

   keytool -list -v -keystore "key store path" -alias "key alias"
4. Enter your key password and this will print out your release SHA1.

Put that SHA1 key into wherever it needed

refere: [How to create SHA1 for Release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933381/10057347)

Comment: Have done all this. Problem doesnt seem to be of sha1 key anymore