# Android studio generating a 3 different APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.1

I wanted to generate a singed APK for my application via Build > Generate Signed APK after this i got 3 different APK one is **app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk** another one is **app-universal-release.apk** and the last one is **app-x86-release.apk**.
What's the difference between each one! What version i should upload to the Google Play Store! 
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Android Studio 3.0.1. 
Here my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.app.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0' //25.3.1
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0' //25.3.1
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0' //25.3.1
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'  //10.2.0
compile 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
compile 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioRecorder:0.3.0'
compile 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8'
compile 'com.github.halysongoncalves:pugnotification:1.8.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you must read that [Generate signed apk android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268520/generate-signed-apk-android-studio)

It always for market
`release {....`