# Android Studio signature v1 or v2 missing

Tags: android

I am trying to generate a signed bundle or apk to upload the file on PlayStore, but the problem is that it is not showing me an option to select v1 or v2 signature. If I go further without these 2 options, then I don't even see the apk file under 'build' folder.

Generate signed apk window

[image]

Build/output/apk folder

[image]

Any solutions please?

VERSIONS

- Android Studio 3.3
- Gradle 4.10.1

Comment: Did you create a key to use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20268520/1531971 (Start from the beginning and check each step.)

Comment: Can you verify if downgrading to Gradle 3.2.0 works?

Comment: @zun it's not working even if I downgrade the version. I am not able to see the v1 and v2 checkboxes while generating the signed build.

Comment: were you able to resolve?

Comment: @WISHY Try my answer

Comment: have you solved it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: Using these settings with Generate Signed Apk windows does not sign the apk with v1.

Comment: How do you know that not sign the APK with V1?

Comment: I use `apksigner verify` to verify the signatures and the result indicates that the app it only signed by v2. Anyway, It seems that apps having `minSdkVersion` >= 24 won't be signed with v1.

Comment: Because Android 7.0 and later support v2, not v1. 
https://source.android.com/security/apksigning#v2

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the store I was trying to upload my APK, required apps to be signed with v1.

Comment: Um... I don't have any idea about this problem. I'm sorry I can't help.