# I have an issue when I try to publish an Android app

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to publish an Android application but I always get this message (check the picture)

Issue 1: 
[image]

And when I generate an Android App Bundle and try to publish it I get this error(check the picture)

Issue 2:
[image]

I hope someone has an answer to this!

Comment: First one clearly says, your app has the unused code: Remove that
Second is you are signing your app with a different key store than, previously uploaded

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268520/generate-signed-apk-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps correctly, this should help :

**Step 1**

Go to Build>Generate Signed APK>Next (module selected would be your module , most often called "app")

**Step 2**

Click on create new

**Step 3**

- Fill in the form with the required details. The confusing bit it is where it asks for a `Key Store Path`.
- Click on the icon on the right with the 3 dots ("..."), which will open up a navigator window asking you to navigate and select a .jks file.
- Navigate to a folder where you want your keystore file saved and then at the `File Name` box at the bottom of that window, simply enter a name of your liking and the OK button will be clickable now.
- What is happening is that the window isnt really asking you chose a .jks file but rather it wants you to give it the location and name that you want it to have.

**Step 4**

Click on *Next* and in the new studio (3.1) you have give password and certififcates, please provide that. then select the build variant `Release`. It is done.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue can be fixed by updating your android studio and generate app as a bundle not as apk. Build-> Generate a signed apk/Bundle-> Android App Bundle.

The second issue is, the wrong keystore. you have to keep your keystore safely once it is lost you cant update your app. if you are publishing for the first time no problem you can generate a new keystore with different application id, and you can upload it.