# What is the keystore in android?

Tags: android, apk, keystore, signed-apk

I am new in android and I have made a app and I am thinking to publish it on play store but I do not know much about keystore and what is signed APK .

I did search on youtube and Google and also on stack overflow that help me

[Stackoverflow link 1](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268520/generate-signed-apk-android-studio&hl=en-IN)

[Stackoverflow link 2](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio/19876060%2319876060&hl=en-IN&tg=453&pt=24#a.19876060)

According videos and these link I am able to make .APK of android project but I am confused with some blog that say to make signed APK and save keystore in gradle file or something similar like that . Also some blog Says if you want to update your app you should store keystore locally

And I am getting very confused . Pleas explain me what is the process . Thank You .

Comment: visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore

Comment: Thank you for response but it does not full fill my question .

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to generate signed apk while publish app on play store for that purpose you have to select path(key store path) where .jks file is generated that contain details app info(keystore file info) & other signing authority details

Comment: Where should store ?

Comment: You can store it anywhere It is just path to store file but remember path where you are going to store it. This generated file is nothing but signed apk.