# Andriod APK not getting installed on devices

Tags: android, installation

I had created an application on android studio in kotlin language,I did directly run it on my android phone through USB cable and the apk works fine but the problem is when i try to send it through whatsapp, email or any other sources, the apk does not get installed in other devices. Also from my device the size of APK gets reduced while sending it. It shows "APP NOT INSTALLED AS PACKAGE APPEARS TO BE INVALID "

Does anyone know how to figure out the problem?

I tried to send it through WhatsApp, email, telegram, through apk as well as zip file but shows same result

Answer (score 0):

A `signed apk` is required to install on phones( where developer options is not enabled)

follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/38755739/7923782 to create a signed apk.

Also for susequent updates you need to use same *.jks file. So preserve the *.jks file.