# get android release Certificate Fingerprints

Tags: android, firebase, certificate, android-fingerprint-api

I am using Android Studio on Mac El Capitan. How do I get the release Certificate Fingerprints? I need it for Firebase. I am not sure exactly how to get it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to test it (*with the debug fingerprint*), run the following command in any directory with the terminal.

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

Then copy the SHA1 value and paste it into your Firebase console.

[image: Fingerprints]

---

Be careful, the above will work for the debug environment, if you want to set up the **release fingerprint** you will have to create a keystore, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore) to see how to do it, and then run the same command but instead of `~/.android/debug.keystore` you should put `~/YOUR/PATH/TO/KEYSTORE`

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/YOUR/PATH/TO/KEYSTORE -list -v
```

---

[Android: What is a keystore file, and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849558/android-what-is-a-keystore-file-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: Thanks, one correction: the alias should be the actual alias, not androidebugkey. At least that's how I got mine to work. Thanks.

Comment: That generates a SHA-256 RSA key. I want SHA-1 to support O-Auth signing.

Comment: if you're using Android Studio v3.6.2 and want to get the info for the `keytool` command, from the menu go to: "Build" > "Generate Signed Bundle / APK"  click Next

Answer (score 8):

As this question is to get RELEASE certificate fingerprint, easy way to get RELEASE fingerprint is,

Open terminal

Go to directory where project's .jks file located

Finally get it by,

> keytool -exportcert -alias ALIAS_NAME -keystore KEYSTORE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION -list -v

Comment: ALIAS_NAME can be found in build.gradle (app) under `release` in `signingConfigs`. `keyAlies "myreleasekey"`

Comment: You saved me. Thanks

Comment: `-alias` doesn't seem to matter. I tried the command with and without it and got the same output

Comment: @lasec0203, bro you save me! thank you very very  much : )

Answer (score 2):

Example :

*ALIAS_NAME_HERE* : **kakha**

*KEY_FULL_PATH* : **C:\Users\kakha\key.jks**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias "ALIAS_NAME_HERE"-keystore "KEY_FULL_PATH" -list -v
```

Answer (score 1):

as @lasec0203 said, you dont need to use alias...

Just use this code;

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "/fullpath/upload-keystore.jks"
```

and after that, enter your keystore than you will get the your certificate fingerprint.