# How to add SHA-1 to android application

Tags: android, firebase, sha1, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to create a dynamic link in Firebase, when I'm selecting the android app, it shows an error saying "Add SHA-1 to this android app", I've already added a credential, but I'm not sure how exactly do I "add SHA-1 to the app"

How is this done?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode) to get SHA-1 key from your android studio and add it to your firebase project

Comment: I already got the SHA-1 key, but I don' know how to add it to my firebase project

Comment: for Android Studio 4.2 see stackoverflow.com/a/67546584/11365488

Comment: #3 worked for me  ---  https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-get-sha-1-key-in-android-studio-for-firebase/

Answer (score 190, accepted):

SHA-1 generation in android studio:

[image: change firebase project setting]

[image: Press add fingerprint button]

---

1. Select Gradle in android studio from right panel
2. Select Your App
3. In Tasks -> android-> signingReport

Double click `signingReport`.

[image: How to get sha1 fingerprint]

---

You will find the SHA-1 fingerprint in the "**Gradle Console**"

Add this SHA-1 fingerprint in firebase console

[image: Add SHA1 fingerprint]

Comment: remember in the output of signing report copy both the release and debug sha1.

Comment: Couldn't get SHA.

Comment: well, it took me some time to find the "Select gradle" because the panel was in the right size. :))))

Comment: Android Studio 3.3: Click on the elephant icon in the Gradle panel, select the project, type in the Command line: "signingReport", click OK

Comment: This totally worked, but Android Studio saw fit to switch my default configuration to creating a signing report instead of running the app. Just a heads up in case running the app breaks for you after finding this value.

Comment: Can't find: "Select Gradle in android studio from right panel"

Comment: The answer gives you the debug key, check this answer if you are using another key for production

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297493/get-android-release-certificate-fingerprints

Comment: For anyone searching the gradle option,A button "Gradle" is placed tilted vertically on the right side of the window.

Comment: I didn't find debug sha1. I only see md5, sha1, sha256.

Comment: this works but is it the same sha1 that's used in production or its for debug purposes only??

Answer (score 180):

If you are using [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) you need to use the SHA1 from google play since Google will replace your release signing key with the one on googles server

[image]

Comment: This needs to be a lot higher. I totally missed that my key is just for uploading and then google resigns it on its own. Took me better part of a morning to realize this

Comment: Really helpful!  The Google App Signing SHA1 has to be added to the list of SHA1's on your services.

Comment: Lifesaver! This should be highlighted in the [Google App Bundle documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423). They mention it under **Tips and Best Practices** at the bottom of the page. However, it is unclear what is required and how to implement.

Comment: Had to use upload key certificate's SHA-1 and SHA-256. Thanks btw.

Comment: Would be helpful to mention _where you can find that_ in google play:  On the left hand side in https://play.google.com/console go to ***Release > Setup > App Integrity*** then click the App Signing tab

Answer (score 57):

Alternatively you can use command line to get your SHA-1 fingerprint:

for your debug certificate you should use:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

you should change "`c:\Users\user`" with the path to your windows user directory

if you want to get the production SHA-1 for your own certificate, replace "`C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore`" with your custom KeyStore path and use your KeystorePass and Keypass instead of android/android.

Than declare the `SHA-1` fingerprints you get to your firebase console as Damini said

Comment: You need to CD to the java bin folder for keytool to work. For me it was, `C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin` although you might have a general java edition installed directly in `C:\Program Files\Java\...`

Answer (score 44):

MacOS just paste in the Terminal:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: work for me , thank ..

Comment: can we add multiple SHA-1 to firebase for example one for debug and other for production?

Answer (score 36):

for Updated Android Studio(12 May 2021)

1. Click on Gradle right side
2. Click on the elephant icon and type the command

```
gradle signingReport
```

press Enter

Now, you will see BUILD SUCCESSFUL in the Run window that you can open from bottom
just scroll that window upward and you will find your SHA1 key there.
Add this key to firebase

1. In your Project settings, go to the Your apps card.
2. Select the Firebase Android app to which you want to add a SHA fingerprint.
3. Click Add fingerprint.
4. Enter or paste the SHA fingerprint, then click Save.

At last, while running your App please check you change the run configuration to app
else only the signingReport Task would be running again and again.

Comment: thanks its work...thanks for last line

Comment: This creates multiple SHA fingerprints for me. Which one should I choose

Comment: ideally, you should get two fingerprints SHA1 and SHA256. Do you have multiple modules in the project? else share some more details

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Google Play App Signing, you don't need to add your SHA-1 keys manually, just login into Firebase go into "project settings"->"integration" and press a button to link Google Play with firebase, SHA-1 will be added automatically.

Comment: As we know its totally fine to link Firebase and Google Play, this is a super easy way to get rid of the SHA generation and integration steps. Within a minute i was able to make my Live app's google sign in bug go away. Thanks.

Comment: I am using phone number OTP firebase authentication in my app so i added my project in the firebase console and also added SHA-1 & SHA-256. Then i uploaded my project to Google Play Store and link it with my project in the firebase. Now, SHA-1 on the Google Play Store is different than the firebase one. Is it a problem ?? Thank you

Comment: If that sha was added during firebase integration with google play, that sha should be right.

Answer (score 15):

Run this command from your `android` directory.

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

If you're not in the `android` directory already, run this instead:

```
cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: This is a good answer because the command displays the fingerprints for all of the app's Build Types and Flavors

Answer (score 9):

Just In case: while using the command line to generate the SHA1 fingerprint, be careful while specifying the folder path. 
If your User Name or android folder path has a space, you should add two double quotes as below:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\User Name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 7):

Try pasting this code in CMD:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Comment: what is the password?

Comment: it is your mac's password

Answer (score 6):

For linux Ubuntu Open Terminal and Write :-

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, open the Command Prompt program. You can do this by going to the Start menu

```
  keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

On Mac/Linux, open the Terminal and paste

```
   keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 4):

linux os terminal run this :

```
  keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass androi
```

Answer (score 3):

when I generate **sha1 key** using android studio

`Gradle -> Tasks -> android-> signingReport` and **double click**

That sha1 key is **worked in debug** mode but **not worked** when i build **singed APK**

so I generated **sha 1** key using **cmd** it work

- go to java\jdk version\ bin  folder

example

```
C:\>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin
```

and type

```
keytool -exportcert  -keystore {path of sign jks key } -list -v
```

example

```
keytool -exportcert  -keystore F:\testkey\damithk.jks -list -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead Of Writing Command, You can Follow the Following Steps For Copy SHA

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you              will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List)
6. Click on Tasks/Android
7. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar).

Answer (score 1):

**Run this command**

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 1):

From your project directory for example:

**E:\practice\firebase_auth_app>**

Write:

```
cd android
```

And it must be like this example: **E:\practice\firebase_auth_app\android>**

and then write:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run the keytool utility provided with Java to get the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate. You should get both the release and debug certificate fingerprints.

To get the release certificate fingerprint:
**keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias  -keystore**

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and the best option, just open root directory in Command prompt and run "gradlew signingReport" this command.

Answer (score 0):

To get the release certificate fingerprint, follow this easy detailed step.

Right click on your

> android folder

> add new file

name it 'key.properties'. (without the single quotation of course)

add this lines

> storePassword=any unique password

> keyPassword=re-enter unique password

> keyAlias=upload

> storeFile= we'll put this later on

On your terminal, add the following and Continue.

On Mac/Linux

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload

On windows

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload

On password, enter the unique store password you put.
On certificate information, just leave it blank and Continue. At the end, type yes to confirm your information and Continue.

Go to the specified path where your upload-keystore.jks file is put, copy the file or move it to your project. Specifically under this folder.

> android/app

Go back to your key.properties file and specify where the upload-keystore.jks path is under storeFile. i.e.

> ../app/upload-keystore.jks

Go to

> android/app/build.gradle

On the file, click

> Open for Editing in Android Studio

> New Window

On the new window terminal, add

> ./gradlew signingReport

and Continue.

Search for the results where both the variant and the config are

> release

Under that, that's your release keys.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging apk in android studio go to terminal and type:

```bash
cd app/build/outputs/apk/debug
```

then type:

```bash
keytool -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk
```

You will get your SHA1 and SHA256 there.

Change path for release with debug.

Comment: Use code blocks for describing any commands in ternimal