# Google Sign In not working when built in my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

A third-party has developed the main structure for my app, including a Google Sign In. When they test it, it works. When I run the APK that they built, it works. When I build using the project files, it fails with a `handleSignInResult:false` error.

I've reinstalled Android Studio, installed all the possible SDKs, but to no avail. Does anybody have any idea why one project will build successfully on one computer, but not on mine?

Could it be something to do with the SHA-1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes...You guessed it right.Its about SHA-1 Key.

You need to add you SHA-1 key generated from your PC keystore

[How to get SHA-1 from Android Studio ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)

Than add that key in your Firebase console or in Google Console

[How to add SHA-1 key to console ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application)

Comment: Success! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need SHA-1 key for integrate google sign in we need to register this key in google developer or google api console,
As per my or other experiance SHA-1 key will change when you change your systm so you need to replace your SHA-1 key with latest from your systme.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Generate Your SHA-1  Release Key for Gmail Login After Build Apk**

**Follow step**

1.Open CMD terminal

Goto Java folder using 
1. cd java
2. cd jdk1.8.0_112
3. cd bin

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin>

Enter Following Command:

keytool -list -v -keystore "PATH OF .jks Keystore" -alias  android

Note: android is my Keystore Alias

then you will get this : Enter keystore password(Enter your keystore password)

Answer (score 0):

Just update your sha-1 to firebase and goo to tools->Firebase->Authentication->click Connect to firebase.It worked for me;)

Get your sha from Gradle->app->task->android->click Signing report
copy the sha1 past to firebase project settings bottom.