# Android app not working after published to Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication, google-play

How can I fix  firebase authentication error?
I generated a release APK of my app and it works fine on devices users can login as they should.

Then the problem occurs when I have published the very same working APK on the play store and I install from there (playstore).
I get the error that

> the app is not authorised to use firebase Authentication. please
>   verify that the package name and SHA1 are configured in the firebase
>   console

Comment: Could you follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application) and check the SHA matches your release cert

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it after hours of a headache.

When you publish your apk to the play store, you get assigned with a singing certificate SHA1. That you have to add to your firebase console.

Comment: For my case, I added all SHA1 and when I generate a signed .apk and install on the phone, everything works fine but when I published a signed .aab bundle, an error comes "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console" Kindly advise me, this has taken me over 4 days but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same issue. In my case, i had signed my APK and had added the SHA-1 to my Firebase Authentication. But while publishing to Play Store i have opted in for Google Play App Signing. And when we create a release in Play Console, Google replaces the Release Signing Key with Google's maintained key.

The Google Key's SHA-1 can be found in Release Management - App Signing - App Signing Certificate in your Google Play Console.
You will need to add that key's SHA-1 to your Firebase Authentication. And it will work.