# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken - error UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE

Tags: android, google-api, registration

I'm getting the following error while running a test app that uses the google picasa API
I understand I need to register my apk but I haven't found a clear explanation on how to do that and if it's free?

```
03-21 13:58:35.872 14611-3438/? W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
03-21 13:58:35.880 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse E/GooglePhotosFragment: failed to get accountUNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
03-21 13:58:35.881 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
03-21 13:58:35.883 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzat(Unknown Source:121)
03-21 13:58:35.883 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzau(Unknown Source:0)
03-21 13:58:35.884 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zza(Unknown Source:21)
03-21 13:58:35.884 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zzc(Unknown Source:67)
03-21 13:58:35.884 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source:3)
03-21 13:58:35.885 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source:5)
03-21 13:58:35.885 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source:0)
03-21 13:58:35.885 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.odysseyDesigns.googlePhotos.PicasaClient$4.call(PicasaClient.java:183)
03-21 13:58:35.885 31919-31919/com.odysseyDesigns.photosintegrationcourse W/System.err:     at com.odysseyDesigns.googlePhotos.PicasaClient$4.call(PicasaClient.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register your sha1 in Firebase Project following this instructions

[How to add SHA-1 to android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application)