# Working on single Firebase project from two machines

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a single project which is synced on two different machines. I have Android Studio and the emulator successfully installed on both machines. I also have successfully implemented Firebase + Google authentication. When I open the emulator on the first machine and run the app, everything works fine but when I run the same project on the second machine using the same user, the authentication fails. If it try to print the error it says:

```
Google sign in failed! Error 10:
```

How can I make both authentications work on both machines? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `SHA-1` key of the second machine in your `firebase` project.
The process is well explained already in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application) post. Please check it out in case you need clarification.