# Cannot authenticate to Firebase API

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

I'm trying to configure firebase API to be used with my nativescript application.
In fact, i don't know how to configure it anymore.

I have my private keystore and another one (managed by google) in my Google Play Console.
Which one fingerprint should i use on Firebase Console?
Tried both separated and together too.

In app still receiving:
`'Make sure you\'ve uploaded your SHA1 fingerprint(s) to the Firebase console. Status: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}'`
error message.

Any tips?

Edit:
Added two fingerprints, updated google-services.json and still not working.
[Firebase Console Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4YoG.png)

Comment: You need to create SHA1 and add to the project. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39144864/6454463)

Comment: I have two different SHA fingerprints. One from Google Play Console (sign-in certificate) and one from my local keystore (using it to sign APK file during build).
Which one is the right fingerprint? None of them seem to be the correct one.

Comment: you can add both SHA in the project

Comment: Did that. And still same error. Also updated google-services.json.

Comment: Are you testing a release build or you are simply using `tns run | debug`?

Comment: tns run android --bundle

Answer (score 0):

Done!

I was wrong.

There are three types of keystores.

- Upload keystore - this one we are using for building production app.
- Signing keystore - (might be) maintained by google for in-store application signing.
  and...

...drums.vaw...

- Debug keystore - created during the installation of Google SDK, used for... yes, you know for what purpose. It is located in ~/.android/debug.keystore, password is android.

Clue was to retrieve SHA-1 fingerprint from debug keystore.

Comment: I've tried adding the debug one to my config but I still can't get the authentication to work. It says I still need to add the SHA1 fingerprint