# Android Google auth wierd issue

Tags: android, firebase, google-authentication

I implemented google sign in in my app and it works perfectly on debug mode, but in release mode i get an error like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.e.trackitapp, PID: 23159
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=421, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.e.trackitapp/com.e.trackitapp.Activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'c.e.u0.a.a.c.a c.e.u0.a.a.b.l()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4453)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4495)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'c.e.u0.a.a.c.a c.e.u0.a.a.b.l()' on a null object reference
    at com.e.trackitapp.Activities.LoginActivity.a(:86)
    at com.e.trackitapp.Activities.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(:108)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7590)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4446)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4495) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

The google accounts dialog comes up, it asks me to allow "my app" to use my datas them it shuts down when i clock allow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add production SHA1 key to Firebase settings? I think you may missed it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39144864/3614334

Comment: Yes, i did add it, and also replaced the google-services.json