# How to disable captcha Otp verification in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, one-time-password

Here is Dependences i am using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0')
```

Here is the code iam using
[OTP oncodesend Funtion not called onVerificationCompleted called in some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056281/otp-oncodesend-funtion-not-called-onverificationcompleted-called-in-some-devices?noredirect=1#comment118532407_67056281)

All these Process follow but still captcha when otp verification

[How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android)

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and structures as text in the question, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Comment: check these anwers https://stackoverflow.com/a/65230860/9942608 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66668640/9942608