# How to disable OTP Captcha in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I'm working on a Google sign in that sends an OTP to a phone number, however when I update the dependencies, a captcha appears. How can I get rid of it?

All methods are implemented by myself.

Using the Google Console, you can enable your Android Device Verification.

in firebase, add sha-256 and SHA-1 Also Add playconsole sha-1 and sha 256 as well.

However, the captcha is still not removed.

Is there anyone who can assist me with this?

here is dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.1.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
 implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:12.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
 implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.1'
```

these all dependencies i am using
google play services dependencies are

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
```

I also implement all methods that are answer in stackoverflow
[follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android)

Here is my gradebuild file

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the settings in Firebase,
2. Click on `App Check`,
3. Click on the package name,
4. Enable `safetyname`,
5. Save.

This should work if you implemented all methods.

Use release `Sha-1` and `Sha-256`.

Enable Android device verification from the Google Console.

Comment: Solved thanks th9i step is remaining :) save my day