# Can we avoid the verifying you are not a robot for firebase authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I did a code where if we enter mobile then a otp appears on our mobile phone. That code is running properly no doubt in that but everytime its opening verifying you are not a robot page. Can we avoid that page? By The Way the code is in java in android studio not kotlin or flutter.

Comment: That sort of verification is called a captcha, or in this case it's re-captcha, so you might find an answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bandroid%5D+recaptcha

Comment: So you want to remove the re-captcha step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android)