# Firebase ReCaptcha opening even after using PlayIntegrity API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-play-integrity-api

Since SafetyNet is deprecated, I tried using PlayIntegrity to get rid of the ReCaptcha popup that opens when using phone authentication from Firebase.

But even after enabling it and initializing the app check in Flutter, the ReCaptcha is still opening.

```
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
  );
```

And the otp message contains my project-url instead of the app name.

After some [searching I found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72338293/13014243) that I need to register my app in **both** SafetyNet and PlayIntegrity, for captcha verification not to come. But since SafetyNet is not accepting any new projects, I can't register my app in it.

I have tried a lot but nothing is fixing this issue, please help me.

Comment: Just was wondering if you got an answer for this. Thanks in advance Mitul.

Comment: @MyHelper didn't get an answer yet 

Comment: Okay. Thanks for letting me know Mitul. If I get something I'll post it here.

Comment: @MyHelper found this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75813278/13014243

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) in 2023?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75603944/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-in-2023)