# Native firebase reCaptcha

Tags: firebase, react-native

How to disable reCaptcha for firebase phone login in react native.

I don't really know what to do, I don't have perfect knowledge of react native.

Answer (score 0):

To disable reCAPTCHA during Firebase phone login, you need to follow different steps for Android and iOS.

### For Android devices

Check out the answers in this thread:

[How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android)

### For iOS devices

Enable silent APNs notification as shown here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#enable-app-verification

---

NOTE: It is not possible to disable reCAPTCHA when testing the application on simulator devices.