# Is there any solution for removing reCaptcha from firebase-auth?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

How to remove reCAPTCHA verification when using PhoneAuth Provider of Firebase Auth into Flutter, March 2023.

I have registered my app to App Check in firebase console with play integrity. Also I have added the code for that in my app as below.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
    // Default provider for Android is the Play Integrity provider. You can use the "AndroidProvider" enum to choose
    // your preferred provider. Choose from:
    // 1. debug provider
    // 2. safety net provider
    // 3. play integrity provider
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
  );
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

But Still Not Working[image: Here You can see I have registered my app.]

Comment: Are you looking for [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android).