# Disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, safetynet

After entering phone number Recaptcha is showing for a few seconds.
Foloowed this qestion: [How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android)
But the [Android DeviceCheck API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com) is deprocated.
Went instead to [SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation), and also, deprecated, suggested to [Play integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity)
But still, after enabling it I see the reCaptcha
(The app is not in Play store, running in locally)

Comment: We have recently released [Firebase Auth 21.2.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#auth_v21-2-0) which adds support for the Play Integrity API. Unfortunately, you'll still see the reCaptcha if you're running it locally. At the moment it only uses the Play Integrity API if the app is on the Play Store.