# How to disable RECAPTCHA when an user authenticate to android app with phone number (by OTP) in firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, recaptcha, one-time-password

I have created a mobile app using flutter and added phone number verification using firebase authenticate. However, When I trying to sign in by providing the phone number, It goes to web page and shows RECAPTCHA. After few seconds it sends the OTP. How can I prevent from the RECPTCHA?

I added the SHA1 and SHA256 in the firebase console. I tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20forget%20to%20go,reCaptcha%20from%20phone%20auth%20OTP!). But it seems like SafetyNet is deprecated and is no longer accepting new projects. So, It didn't work.  What can be the solution for this?