# How to disable captcha in Firebase phone auth (otp) in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, captcha

`Android Device Check` and `SafetyNet` APIs have been deprecated. I enabled the `Play Integrity API` in Google cloud hoping to get rid of captcha but, still I have not been able to disable it when I go for the phone authentication. I've provided both `sha1` and `sha256` certificates in Firebase project settings as well. I'm testing my app on phsycial device as well as on emulator, but the result is same. This captcha is supper annoying and I want to get rid of it. This question on SO [How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android) isn't helping.