# Flutter google ads not working when signed with release key

Tags: flutter, admob

I have a flutter application where I have implemented [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) . It will work fine if I run the app in debug mode (both real and test ads load). But when I run the app in release mode or if I build the apk and install it in my device, the ads are not loaded.

Some important things to know:

1. I implemented the same ads on a different app and release it then it is working - which means there is no problem in the ads,
2. I implemented different ads from a different app and it was still not working (I have done all the code setup of the ads properly)- which means there is problem with my app,
3. The ads won't work on release mode only - on debug mode, it works absolutely fine (both real and test ads),

Comment: Have you included your release keystore SHA fingerprints to the Google Console ?

Comment: I have implemented Firebase and have included the SHA fingerprints on Firebase Console. I have also published the app on Playstore about 2 days ago and It is still under review.

Comment: You need to add for both debug and release
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application

Comment: I have implemented both debug and release SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints.

Answer (score 0):

My app was in review in playstore and after my app has been successfully published, the ads started to appear immediately. Looks like the app must be published to playstore after releasing it with release key.