# Which SHA1 fingerprints should i use in my Firebase projects?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-console

I have an app in google play console, that uses two Firebase projects(one in open testing and another one is for production), and i've added API keys restriction in Google cloud. But i don't understand which SHA1 fingerprints i should add too my Firebase projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this guide](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en) on how to add a SHA fingerprint to a Firebase Android app.
Following the link in the 1st step I found [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth), which explains how to get the SHA-1 from the Google Play Console and also how to self-sign your application.

Additionally I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application) which accepted answer seems to explain how to self-sign your application [using Gradle's Signing Report](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_gradles_signing_report)