# Apk not upload in google playstore

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play, apk

I had developed my app in xamarin forms and release my android app with playstore. and unfortunately I have to change my system. Now I have done some changes in app and I want to release that new apk in playstore then I am getting this given below:

**You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed 
with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): 
[ SHA1: 70:9A:CF:42:5E:98:B9:4D:B2:F6:B7:2E:AC:C4:64:14:4B:5D:76:18 ] 
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 62:E0:24:5F:18:95:47:95:60:C3:08:B2:D5:16:E8:C5:46:D1:D7:4E ]**

Please help me as I am new with xamarin forms development

Thank you

Comment: If you do not have the original keystone, review the reset answer(s) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apk you uploaded first time(the apk which is live on playstore), had a different signing key compared to the apk you are trying to upload right now.

Once an apk is uploaded on the store, you always have to use the same `applicationId` and signing key as you used for the first time uploading. If your ever loose your key, you can **never** update the same apk again.

Edit:
Starting from May 2017, there is an option to [upload your keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770288/7360848) and back them up in google servers. But you have to opt in to this service. They will backup they keys you uploaded and give them back when you need them. But if you don't opt in for this service already, before losing your keys. you are out of luck

Comment: Not true, you can request Play support to reset the cert and it will take a couple of days... (this support service has been available since last year) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file

Comment: thanks for the info. I knew that. It is only available is you opt in for the service, giving them permission to store your key. But if you didn't opt in or don't want to, you still have no option left. check here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using different keystore singing file from your previous version keystore file. Please make sure use the same file every time when you are creating signed api for google play store upload.

Keystore file is generated when we create signed apk first time for upload to play store. This file is with extension .jks

References

- https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
- https://headjack.io/tutorial/create-android-keystore-file/
- [What is Android keystore file, and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849558/what-is-android-keystore-file-and-what-is-it-used-for)