# Flutter What is keystore file in apk build?

Tags: flutter, google-play

I tried to build new apk file of my app, but got error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file not set for signing config release

previous version of my app that don't have purchases was build correctly but right now it's dosen't.

I found a lot informations how to set KeyStore file but nothing about what is it.

May you explain what is it

Comment: Here you will find a good explanation in easy words  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849903/744680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically **Keystore** is used to store `private key` and identity `certificates` that a specific program should present to both parties (server or client) for verification.

The `Android Keystore system` lets you store cryptographic keys in a container to make it more difficult to extract from the device. Once keys are in the keystore, they can be used for cryptographic operations with the key material remaining non-exportable. Moreover, it offers facilities to restrict when and how keys can be used, such as requiring user authentication for key use or restricting keys to be used only in certain cryptographic modes. See Security Features section for more information.

The `Keystore` system is used by the KeyChain API, introduced in Android 4.0 (API level 14); the Android Keystore provider feature, introduced in Android 4.3 (API level 18); and the Security library, available as part of Jetpack. This document goes over when and how to use the Android Keystore provider.

For details information please refer to this -

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore